# How to connect a multi-module application to a database?

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa, domain-driven-design, multi-module

Building an multi module application using Spring Boot, Implementing a hexagonal architecture where I have a domain module, application module and infrastructure module. Each module has a :domain dependency, where I have implemented the models and my business logic, In the application layer I have my controllers, dtos and the main application class where I start the application.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"ez.ndvz.application", "ez.ndvz","ez.ndvz.infrastructure.persistance","ez.ndvz.infrastructure"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

In my infrastructure module I have another submodule called persistence where I defined my entities and jpa repositories at the same time I have my db connection properties:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/booksDB
    username: *********
    password: ****
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver

    jpa:
      database: POSTGRESQL
      show-sql: true
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: update
      properties:
        hibernate:
          dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Now when I run the application from my Application Main Class I get the following error:

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and
> no embedded datasource could be configured.
>
> Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
>
> Action:
>
> Consider the following:
> If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
> If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently
> active).
>
> Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52985',
> transport: 'socket*************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO
> START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and
> no embedded datasource could be configured.
>
> Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
>
> Action:
>
> Consider the following:
> If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
> If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently
> active).
>
> Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52985',
> transport: 'socket And I get some logs saying :
> RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JDBC - Could not
> safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface
> ez.ndvz.persistance.repository.ImageRepository; If you want this
> repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities
> with one of these annotations:
> org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table

. for each of my entities

Could It Be That Spring Boot isn't recognizing the application.yaml file in the persistance submodule when starting? How do I fix this

Comment: Can you share GitHub link of the project ?

Comment: https://github.com/EnisZenuni/Nedviznosti 
This is the last merge I am still working on somethings but this is the overall structure so far I think it can be used to solve the problem @Andrei Lisa